# What is "ms: A" HTTP header?

Tags: http-headers

Some sites, including [twitter.com](https://twitter.com) send

```
 ms: A
```

HTTP header, among normal ones. What does that do, or is it custom header that was prefix with `X-` before [RFC 6648](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6648)?

As "ms" is rather generic term, Google does not provide any meaningful results.

Comment: Can you add an example request where you get such a header in the response?